# C++ - Class constructor creates objects, but the result of the construction is different

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, constructor

I have a class project in C++. The goal is to sort a phonebook (txt file) when inserting in a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Here are the classes :

```
class Person
{
    public:
        string Name
        string Firstname;
        string Adress;
        int PostalCode;
        string Telephone;
        Person();
        ~Person();
};

class Link
{
    friend class List;
    Link *next;
    Person *pers;
    public:
        Link();
        Link(string data);
};

class List
{
    // debut is the start of the chained list
    Link *start;
    public:
        List(string data)
        {
            start = NewLinkPerson(data, NULL);
        }
};

Link::Link(string data)
{
    next = NULL;
    Person p;
    p.put_data(data);
    pers = &p;
}

Link::Link()
{
    next = NULL;
    Person p;
    pers = &p;
}
```

And then, the function NewLinkPerson is detailed as such :

```
Maillon * NewLinkPerson(string data, Maillon *ssuiv)
{
    Maillon * nouveau = new Maillon(data);
    nouveau->suiv = ssuiv;
    return nouveau;
}
```

The problem is that the object created is not the one I ordered the program him to create. If I output the object `pers` of type Person in the constructor, it will be filled with the data I asked. 
But when it leaves the constructor, the data is gone, and is filled with random strings from the memory.

What could be causing the issue ? I have tried many things, but none of them seem to works, all mainly returned a Segmentation Fault.

**EDIT** : A function I forgot to put there :

```
void Person::put_data(string data)
{
    int sep1 = data.find("|");
    int sep2 = data.find("|", sep1+1);
    int sep3 = data.find("|", sep2+1);
    int sep4 = data.find("|", sep3+1);
    Name = data.substr(0, sep1);
    Firstname = data.substr(sep1+1, sep2-sep1-1);
    Adress = data.substr(sep2+1, sep3-sep2-1);
    Telephone = data.substr(sep4+1, data.npos);
    string ccode = data.substr(sep3+1, sep4-sep3-1);
    PostalCode = std::stoi(ccode.c_str());
}
```

**Edit 2** : Translated to english

Comment: `pers = &p;` compiles?

Comment: "The problem is that the object created is not the one I ordered him to do." <-- what does this sentence even mean? Who is "him"?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, the g++ compiler told me to put it, because the object pers is a pointer, forgot the * in the post, editing now

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Barry Sorry if it was not clear. What I meant was I order the program to create a new `Maillon` element, and it is filled with the data given, but only when it is created. Once the constructor is exited, the data in the `Maillon` is just a bunch of gibberish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior

```
Link::Link(string data)
{
    next = NULL;
    Person p;
    p.put_data(data);
    pers = &p;
}

Link::Link()
{
    next = NULL;
    Person p;
    pers = &p;
}
```

In both constructors in the above code you create a local `Person`, `p`, and then you have `pers` point to it.  After the constructor ends `p` goes out of scope, gets destroyed and now `pers` points to an object that no longer exists.  Any dereference of `pers` after that will it still points to the deleted object is undefined behavior.

To fix this just get rid of the pointer for `pers`.  If you store it as a value then you do not need any dynamic memory allocation and you get away from pointer syntax.  Link should be

```
class Link
{
    friend class List;
    Link *next;
    Person pers; // no pointer here
    public:
        Link();
        Link(string data);
};
```

And then the constructors can be defined like

```
Link::Link(string data)
{
    next = NULL;
    pers.put_data(data);
}

Link::Link()
{
    next = NULL;
}
```

If you have to have `pers` as a pointer then you can allocate persistent storage for it with `new`.  If you do that then you need to make sure you `delete` it in the destructor of the class and that you have copy symantics.  For more on this see [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: But if I don't create a person in the constructor object, where else could I create it, and what would be the syntax ? I tried this : `(name of a link)->pers = new Person;` but it raised me an error when compiling.

Comment: @ThibaultdeVillèle Use the `new` inside `Link`'s constructor: `pers` is a private member of `Link`, and cannot be accessed externally from an instance of `Link`

Comment: @KABoissonneault There is no reason to use new for `pers` when we can just get rid of it being a pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am incredibly greatful for your answer, unfortunately since this is a project for my programming class, `pers` being a pointer is _necessary_, and cannot be avoided. If so, should I use the answer from @KABoissonneault ?

Comment: @ThibaultdeVillèle Remember to `delete pers` inside `Link`'s destructor (`~Link`) if you choose to allocate `pers` dynamically

Comment: @ThibaultdeVillèle Yes you have to.  I added some more to the answer

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you very much. You helped me more than I could hope for.

Comment: @ThibaultdeVillèle No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Thanks ! Will do.